# Mail sent with Cloud Functions is not received

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have a realtime database in firebase.
My intention is that when adding an event to one of the branches of the database `"paso1/"`, a welcome email is sent.

I have everything configured with Firebase Cloud Functions, other functions work correctly.
The function that sends this email is received in the "Functions" section of firebase and gives a message of everything correct.

[image]

however, the email is not received at the recipient's address.

I attached the code of my function, because I do not know that it may be failed. The dependencies are included, when deploying in the console everything is ok, when executing the android app that saves a new field in the database, it is registered correctly and the function returns a message "finished with status: ok"

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "MY_EMAIL",
        pass: "MY_EMAIL_PASSWORD"
    }
})

exports.welcomeMail = functions.database.ref("paso1/{id}").onCreate((snap, context) => {
    return sendWelcomeMail ()

});

// aux functions

function sendWelcomeMail() {

    return transport.sendMail({
        from: "Sergio <test@test.com>",
        to: "destinationemail@gmail.com",
        subject: "This is a subject",
        text: "Hello my friend!"
     })
        .then(r=>r)
        .catch(e=>e);
}
```

I tried using "paso1/{id}" or "paso1/{uid}" and quite a few changes, but without success.

I appreciate the help to get the mail.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Could this be the problem .... https://serverfault.com/questions/822815/cant-send-email-using-email-function-in-google-cloud-platform   Are you logging exceptions from the APIs?

Comment: Here is an apparent working recipe ... https://dev.to/i_maka/google-cloud-functions-sending-emails-using-gmail-smtp-and-nodemailer-1lij

Comment: Finally, the problem was that I was using the primary password of the sending email account instead of the one generated by Google to send emails from third-party applications.
Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: Hi @Sergio76, good work finding the solution! Could you post it as an answer and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was that I was using the primary password of the sending email account instead of the one generated by Google to send emails from third-party applications.